# KEYEXPIRED on Opensuse repository

Tags: ubuntu, opensuse, gpg

Running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

On running `sudo apt update`, the final lines are as follows:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/osmc/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1482381670
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/osmc/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`apt-key list` shows one key expired:

```
pub   2048R/70F1BBEA 2014-10-14 [expired: 2016-12-22]
uid                  home:osmc OBS Project <home:osmc@build.opensuse.org>
```

(For some reason, `apt-key list | grep “expired:”` returns nothing however.)

Attempting to update this key does not change anything:

```
$ apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 70F1BBEA
Executing: /tmp/tmp.pOcDAzqSkJ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keys.gnupg.net
--recv-keys
70F1BBEA
gpg: requesting key 70F1BBEA from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key 70F1BBEA: "home:osmc OBS Project <home:osmc@build.opensuse.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I also tried running Y PPA Manager and "Try to import all missing GPG keys" but the result was the same.

I'm guessing perhaps I'm running an out-of-date version of Opensuse and need to change it, but I'm uncertain of what it is and how to do this correctly.

Comment: The reason why `apt-key list | grep “expired:”` does not work is because smart quotes is being used. Notice how `“ ”` and `" "` are different. The command will work if you replaced `“ ”` with `" "`, so it becomes `apt-key list | grep "expired:"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adding a third party repository to a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` file or `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you need to make sure the corresponding gpg key is inserted into the apt keystore.

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/osmc/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -    
sudo apt update
```

---

If that doesn't work because the key really expired, remove the error and warning messages. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/osmc-installer.list` and add a hash character ( `#` ) at the beginning of the lines before `deb` to turn them into comments.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/osmc-installer.list
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Update your list of available software packages.

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Thanks - running the wget and updating fixed this issue. I appreciate it.

Comment: I also didn't add the repository so not sure how that happened, but still learning I guess.

Comment: This solution worked mutatis mutandis on my Debian 9 installation: wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_9.0/Release.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: Resource is no longer available!

Comment: @lefterav That key for Debian 9 is expired, but there is a new key for Debian 10 (Release.key) at the [official open SUSE website](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_10/).